# Why Django form is not rendering on my site?

Tags: python, django

What I want to do: I want to have a login form that when details are entered they are saved on the admin side.
My problem: the forms are not showing up on my local host page. See image below:

[image: what the login page looks like, forms are meant to be above sign in button]

Here is the code from the login form app:

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Contact

admin.site.register(Contact)
```

from apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'contact'
```

from forms.py

```
from .models import Contact


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

from models.py:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username} {self.password}'
```

from views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
from .forms import ContactForm


def contact(request):
    template = "home2.html"

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Then finally from the login page:

```
{% load static %} 
<form method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn"><a href="£">Log In</a></button>
      </form>
```

Another thing: forms are connected to the admin side but just do not appear on the login page

Comment: This worked for me, I tested your code.
Could you please show me your urls.py and setings.py

Comment: @AgusMathew yep ill add the settings.py but i dont appear to have a urls.py made in the login app. so do i need to do that? the settings.py apps section: `# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contact',
    'crispy_forms',
]`

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Could you please show me your urls.py in the project folder?

Comment: Can you also check if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: @AgusMathew thanks man i figured it out